# How can I use my second pill without using the first one?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I got a shop upgrade that let me hold two pills. The problem I have now is that I want to use the second pill, but not the first one.

Is it possible to drop one pill or swap them or any other way I can use the second one without using the first one? Assume that I can not grab some other consumable to swap the bad first pill that way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tap (don't hold) the drop button (by default the left Ctrl button or RT).